# There should be at least one variable before saving a graph in Tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow

I have written my first lines with Tensorflow as below. But when i remove line `bias = tf.Variable(2.0, name="bias")` i cannot save my model and Tensorflow raises an exception telling **"No variables to save"**. What is the problem? I don't really need *bias* variable.

```
import tensorflow as tf
ckpt_path = "test/test.ckpt"

w1 = tf.placeholder("float", name="w1")
w2 = tf.placeholder("float", name="w2")
bias = tf.Variable(2.0, name="bias")
feed_dict = {w1: 4, w2: 8}

w3 = tf.add(w1, w2 , name="op_to_restore")

sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

saver = tf.train.Saver() #

print(sess.run(w3, feed_dict))

saver.save(sess, ckpt_path)
```

Comment: Because it has no variable if you remove the `tf.Variable(2.0, name="bias")`, placeholders don't actually contain a value, and w3 is also a placeholder, thus none of them can be saved to a file, if you were working with keras, then it will save, because Keras also saves the Graph as well.hope that answers your question

Comment: Thanks for replying, so how can I save a model without a variable, because it now satisfies my need with only two placeholders.

Comment: In Tensorflow you cannot save the graph, you save the weights and recreate the graph when needed, so no you cannot just save a few placeholders and operations between them the checkpoint only contains variables and values, that is as far as my knowledge goes, if there is a way wait for someone to come and answer or attach a bounty to it and someone might answer it quickly, but yes to the extent of my knowledge TensorFlow cannot save the graph itself.